# PHP - How can I treat the fifth item in a set of results differently?

Tags: php

So I have been googling a lot today to find a way to do this. I could not find a way.
My question is
how do i do this :

if result is a total of 5 then do 'this' for the first 4 results then do something else for the 5th result and above.

I am searing for doing this with php but i have a small feeling this is unpossible.

Comment: A result.. of... what exactly?  `if ($result_count <5){less than 5, do this;} else {its 5 or more, do this;}`

Comment: Perfectly possible, just keep a count of the results as you do things with them, and when the count is 5 (use an if test to check) do that something different

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop then you can try something like this

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if($i ==5){
        //code for value of 5
    }else{
        //code for other values
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm not quite certain what you're asking as I can't see your code, is this what you meant? (the `==` was replaced with `<=`)

```
<?php

    $arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        if($i <=5){
            //code for value of 5
            echo $arr[$i];
        }else{
            //code for other values
        }
    }
```

Comment: will this also show both results? I want it to show all 5 results but for everything above 5 i want it to be doing something else. Thank you tho!